# Application.CreateItem and default store VSTO Outlook 2010-2013

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook VSTO addin (.NET4.0 targeting Office 2010/2013).
It looks like the only way to create an item (e.g. a contact) is to use CreateItem on the Application object

```
 Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olContactItem) as ContactItem
```

Therefore the created item will live in Outlook's default store (see picture). Is there a way to choose the store where it will be created ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MAPIFolder.Items.Add to create an item in a particular folder, but Outlook (playing the big brother who knows best) might still put the item in its default folder for some item types, so you might still use ContactItem.Move().

Comment: That what I was looking for (the Items.Add) thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways for creating a contact item in Outlook.

1. [CreateItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869635.aspx)
2. [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861028.aspx)
3. [CreateItemFromTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865637.aspx)

See [How To: Create a new Outlook Contact item programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/07/outlook-create-contact-item/) for more information.